# How to get margin between my videos?

Tags: html, css

I want to put some space between my videos which are in a inline-block I tried adding a margin-top but it doesn't seem to work? I also want to center my text on the right side of the video?[image]

```
 <div style="display: inline-block;">
   <div class="vidJava">
    <iframe style="clear:left; float: left" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/videoseries?list=PLFE2CE09D83EE3E28"
            width="560px" height="315px" frameborder="0"></iframe>
       <p style="float: left;">lorem upsum unhgt nuhj ifn hh h</p>
    </div>

    <div class="vidJava" style="margin-top:50px;">
        <iframe style="clear:left; float: left" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/videoseries?list=PLFE2CE09D83EE3E28"
                width="560px" height="315px" frameborder="0"></iframe>
        <p style="float: left;">lorem upsum unhgt nuhj ifn hh h</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you add a spacer Div between them with a height of 50px? or sometimes a padding-top will work with a margin-top won't. also .. your iframes are float left, but you don't clear that anywhere within the containing divs .. not sure if that may contribute

Comment: adding <div style="clear:both;height:50px;">&nbsp;</div> before closing the parent divJava divs perhaps? kind of a tweak that should not be necessary .. but ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `overflow:auto` to your `.vidJava` class.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/tBevA/)**

Comment: Thank you, one question though is it correct to have my <p> tag to float left like I have it to achieve text on the right?

Answer (score 1):

Since your iframes are floated to the left, the divs wrapping them are probably collapsed.

Add this to your css

```
.vidJava
{
     overflow:auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<div style="display: inline-block;">
<table>   
<tr>
<div class="vidJava">
    <iframe style="clear:left; float: left" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/videoseries?list=PLFE2CE09D83EE3E28"
            width="560px" height="315px" frameborder="0"></iframe>
       <p style="float: left;">lorem upsum unhgt nuhj ifn hh h</p>
    </div>
</tr>
<tr>
(here you can add or leave it..depend on you)
</tr>
<tr>
    <div class="vidJava" style="margin-top:50px;">
        <iframe style="clear:left; float: left" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/videoseries?list=PLFE2CE09D83EE3E28"
                width="560px" height="315px" frameborder="0"></iframe>
        <p style="float: left;">lorem upsum unhgt nuhj ifn hh h</p>
    </div>
</tr>
<table>
</div>
```

and there you have a division, it's better to order by tables if you want to have your page ordered, is my way of develop, i hope i helped you!

Answer (score -1):

Maybe try using a break in between the video divs. `<br />`